# How to get number of records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am having 25 Lacs records in table , how can i get first 10 lacs after 10 lacs and after that 5 lacs records in sql Server 2008.

Could you please help me in this?

In PL SQL i do like this

```
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE rownum > or rownum < 10
```

Please suggest.

Comment: It depends on the DB that you use

Comment: possible duplicate of [LIMIT / OFFSET in Oracle 11G](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326885/limit-offset-in-oracle-11g)

Comment: You're looking for a way to handle `LIMIT / OFFSET` (or similar clauses from other databases) in Oracle. See this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326885/limit-offset-in-oracle-11g, or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480243/sql-oracle-order-by-and-limit

Comment: @Kayser: The keywords `PL / SQL` and `ROWNUM` can only be Oracle

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [dataKeyColumnName]) AS RowNo, * FROM Temp 
) AS A
WHERE A.RowNo BETWEEN 10 AND 15
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the DB that you use.

For `Oracle` you can use

```
SELECT * FROM(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [tableId]) AS RowNr, * FROM MyTable 
) AS T
WHERE T.RowNr BETWEEN 6 AND 15
```

See also the discussion :
[LIMIT / OFFSET in Oracle 11G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326885/limit-offset-in-oracle-11g)

For `MYSQL` you can use

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

Comment: The keywords PL / SQL and ROWNUM can only be Oracle